# Can't access Azure Appservice protected by AAD from Postman

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service say https://blahablah.azurewebsites.net to which I have hosted an ASP. Net web api project(An api that returns list of to do items by GET request), so that I can access the API without any authentication using https://blahablah.azurewebsites.net/api/TodoItems as i had TodoItems as my controller.

Now when I create an Azure AD and set Advanced Authentication of the app service; I can't access the api on the previous endpoint; When I use postman with the client id, secret, auth and token endpoints, it says my redirect URL is not valid;

So what should be my redirect URL? How can i successfully send a GET request from POSTMAN?

**Update 1**: My endpoints were wrong, and I corrected it to login.microsoftonline.com instead of login.microsoft.com, so I'm getting the access token, but when I'm sending a get request to above api with that token in header, it still says 401 unauthorised.
And i'm using redirect url as https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback

**Update 2**: Here is my configuration

1)I have 2 AAD apps: blahablahAAD aap and PostmanAAD app

2)For app service, blahablah i use the first AAD app thru Express authentication of Azure Active Directory;

3)I have made https://blahablah.azurewebsites.net/api as the first AAD app's Application ID URI, and hence am able to expose https://blahablah.azurewebsites.net/api/TodoItems with TodoItems as scope.

4)I have added the API to "API permissions" of the first AAD app; (uptil now it works well in browser asking me for login and then taking me to the endpoint;)

5) For the PostmanAAD, I use it's client id,secret in Postman and get the token; I send it as request header to API;but it failss

6) I have added PostmanAAD's client id in "Expose API->add client application" of blahablahAAD.

7) I have done step 4 for PostmanAAD also

8) I have granted admin consent to all in default directory.

Note: I haven't added any authorization related code to my ASP .NET web api project that i hosted as app service, but i believe i can access it without writing code(as in AAD will do the task for me).

Comment: Is the redirect URL you requested in postman the same as the redirect URL you set in Azure ad?

Comment: I found out the error for the first part, I was putting the wrong endpoint. I put it as "login.microsoft.com" instead of "login.microsoftonline.com", so now I'm getting the access token, but when I'm sending it as bearer token to my api, it gives 401 unauthorised. I'll update the question.

Comment: Do you add the necessary access rights to the application and grant the administrator consent? Which verification method are you using?

Comment: In my API permssions for the AAD app,(which the app service uses as Express authentication); I have added the above API by exposing it; And the Admin Consent required shows no because I have granted admin consent for default directory

Comment: @CarlZhao I have updated my question with the full configuration;

Comment: How did you request the token? Can you provide detailed steps or screenshots?

Comment: For the token you currently use, can you parse it out according to  https://jwt.io/  and provide a screenshot?

Comment: In Postman, make sure you use the correct resource/scope (depending if you are using v1 or v2 endpoint of AAD). And yeah, inspect the token to make sure it has the correct audience (aud, should be your API's id) and scope.

Comment: I found out the problem, it got corrected when i sent resource url as the GUID ID of the azure aad app(connected to app service) instead of the URI, why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set resource url as the guid of the azure ad app instead of application id url.

Click azure ad app and choose Application Id in Overview.

[image]

Comment: why not the application id url? Why doesn't it work with it? I mean both point to the same thing, right? I mean, since i added this aad app to my app service thru advanced authentication, that means i can uniquely identify the resource(app service) i want to issue tokens for by using the aad app id or URI because it points to the resource

Comment: Where exactly should I enter the GUID from Azure AD? I can't see anything specific in Postman's GUI for that...